# Can I use .Contains() in Linq query?

Tags: linq

I have this query and I am wondering if the .contains() method should work.
I have seen examples using it with string arrays but not with 2 strings.

```
var FolderId = (from f in db.Folders
                where Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath.ToString()).Contains(f.FolderPath.ToString())
                select f.FolderId).FirstOrDefault();
```

The filepath contains the Path of its folder.

The reason I wanted to use .Contains() is because the file that the filePath variable comes from may be in a subfolder and therefore the filePaths folder would not equal the Folder path so I couldn't use the "==" in the where.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Contains` in LINQ query and it will be translated to the under laying data source language,  for example SQL.

**But** your method call `Path.GetDirectoryName` will have a problem in getting translated. So extract that out first and then use it in your query:

```
string directoryName= Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath.ToString());

var FolderId = (from f in db.Folders
                where directoryName.Contains(f.FolderPath)
                select f.FolderId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also make sure not to use `ToString` in LINQ query, that might raise an exception.

Comment: you mean if he is going to use it as it is now, it will not work?

Comment: @Christos, `Contains` would work, but `Path.GetDirectoryName` would fail in case of Linq to SQL or LINQ to entities.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. I did know about LINQ to SQL but I didn't now about LINQ to entities.